# How to pass the variables by using eggplant tool

Tags: variables, eggplant

I am reading the text from one excel sheet. this text is put in to one temp variable.

Now I want to use this temp variable to another script.

is there any command in eggplant?

Comment: Try this if it helps..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212319/read-data-from-external-data-sheet-eggplant

Answer (score 1):

In your other script (named OtherScript in this example), create a handler:

```
to HandlerName Variable1 //Starts the handler.
      //Insert your script commands here 
end HandlerName//Ends the handler.
```

In your current script, run the following line to pass your temp variable to the other script:

```
run OtherScript.HandlerName temp
```

Where temp is the variable you would like to pass from your current script that reads the excel sheet to the other script.